# How to loop a child item in a child item of categories?

Tags: javascript

categories tree

[image: categories tree]

I have the category tree as above, the child of each item has a parent path like this example:
_ Category article 6 - parent: '/category-article-4'
_ Category article 8 - parent: '/category-article-4/category-article-6'
_...
I'm using javascript. 
How can I check if the item has a child, and the loop continues to find the next child?
Look forward to your help?

Comment: Upload your code to codepen, so we can help you.

Comment: Why Codepen? Stackoverflow supports built-in snippets...

Comment: https://codepen.io/minhphan1704/pen/poJMOVp
I have defined default values in the code pen. please help. thanks.

Comment: My question is:
When I moved category2 out of category1, how to loop and update the parent for the child of category 2? @ElmanHuseynov
eg: /category-1/category-2 ==> /category-2

Comment: @HoàngMinhPhan does my solution helps you?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov I have seen it, will follow and let you know the result, thank you very much.

Comment: @HoàngMinhPhan you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will help to loop through all objects and nested objects to define whether it has nested objects or not.

```
var findObjectByLabel = function(obj) {

    if(!obj.child) return obj;

    return findObjectByLabel(obj.child);
};

var test = findObjectByLabel(categoryTree);
console.log(test);
```